# Clarification of the certainty factor in isProbablePrime

Tags: java, rsa, biginteger

My question concerns the the "certainty" factor for the `isProbablePrime()` method for the `BigInteger`. The Java API states that this is:

> "a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is willing to tolerate"

Is this a percentage of uncertainty or some other factor. I need 2 prime number of 512 bit.

Comment: Additionally to the correct answers given, please do not roll your own crypto (except for learning). From the [rsa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsa) tag it seems you wish to implement some RSA? Use `Cipher`s and don't implement it manually, and you don't need to worry about issues in your implementation.

Answer (score 22):

From the [Javadocs for `BigInteger`'s `isProbablePrime` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime%28int%29):

> certainty - a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is willing to tolerate: if the call returns true the probability that this BigInteger is prime exceeds (1 - 1/2<sup>certainty</sup>)

So, the higher the `certainty` number you pass, the more certain you can be, i.e. `100` means it's prime with probability 1 - (1/2)<sup>100</sup>, which is extremely close to 1.

Java accomplishes this by performing Miller-Rabin primality tests, the number of which is based on `certainty` (and a Lucas-Lehmer test).

Comment: For reference: if `certainty` is 10, then `1 - 1/2^10` is approximately 99.9%.

Comment: @LouisWasserman can we use ` certainty = 10 `? I thought certainty ` only ` can be  ` 0, 1 or  -1 ` ?

Comment: @pippilongstocking The documentation specifies that `certainty` can be any integer.  It sounds like you might be mixing it up with the result of `compareTo`, though not even that is actually required to be 0, 1, or -1.